# Avoiding making duplicate panels of controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a web application, but I am not using MVC.

I have pages like: create a task, create a project, create a case...

Everyone of these requests standard information like: StartDate ( a calendar widget, etc), Start time, etc.

If, somewhere down the line, I need to change this standard stuff, say, I need to change the calendar for a textbox, I want it to change everwhere where this is used.

What is a proper way to do this sort of thing?

In the ASP .NET code it would be nice to have like:

```
SchedulePanel.Calendar.Date;
```

It does not have to be panel based or anything, but I basically have a group of controls that I need in many places.

Thanks

Comment: Put the common content on a [master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: `MasterPages` serve a similar purpose but it isn't clear that the questioner wants the same markup in the same location on every page. `UserControls` will give you more granularity where you put a particular `widget` but that widget will always look the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all of those controls into a UserControl and add that whenever it is needed. Like Robert said, if it is needed on virtually every page, then put those controls into the master page.

Answer (score 1):

asp.net `UserControls` are really idea for this type of situation.

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/using/

Comment: I totally agree: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET

Comment: @MUG4N, Possibly an even better link!

Answer (score 0):

Please explain more this statement:`I want it to change everwhere where this is used.`

If I undesrstand correctly you can put all your controls in a `User Control` and in code behind declare `public` variable and change your controls in `set` section